# Add resource-strings to Char Sequence

Tags: android

I have the following problem:

I created a Char Sequence and was able to name 4 units. I would however rather use strings from my XML file for localization purposes. Is there any way to achieve that?

```
final CharSequence[] choices = 

        //want to add strings here i.e. R.strings.lemonade  
        {"Coke", "Pepsi" , "Sprite" , "Seven Up" };

builderType.setSingleChoiceItems( choices, selected, new OnClickListener()
                    {.......
```

Error message:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to CharSequence

Answer (score 7):

There's another overload of [`AlertDialog.Builder.setSingleChoiceItems()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28int,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) that takes in an `int` resource id for a string array of items. Put the following in an xml in `res/values` e.g. `strings.xml`:

```
<string-array name="choices">
    <item>Coke</item>
    <item>Pepsi</item>
    <item>Sprite</item>
    <item>Seven Up</item>
</string-array>
```

Then you can use it as:

```
builderType.setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.choices, selected, new OnClickListener(), ...
```

For generic cases, you can also load string array resources with `Resources.getStringArray()` as suggested by @Egor.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `string-array` in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="choices">
    <item>Coke</item>
    <item>Pepsi</item>
    <item>Sprite</item>
    <item>Seven Up</item>
</string-array>
```

Then fetch it from resources

```
String[] choices = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.choices);
```

Then use it in `setSingleChoiceItems()` as is, since `String` implements `CharSequence`.